# Gradient inequality lower semicontinuity

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

How can we prove that if $\phi_n\to \phi$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ then:

$$\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla\phi_n(x)| dx\geq \int_{\Omega} |\nabla\phi(x)|\ dx$$

? If you know some reference where I could find some type of inequalities I will be thankful.

Comment: Lemma of Fatou?

Comment: not quite, you do not have pointwose convergence

Comment: @Meowdog Why not? If $\nabla \phi_n \to \nabla \phi$ in $L^2$, we have a.e. pointwise convergence (on a subsequence).

Comment: Yes, on a subsequence, not on the entire sequence.  The subsequence might have a different $\liminf$.

Comment: @Meowdog first take the subsequence that realizes the lim inf, then take the pointwise a.e. converging subsequence. I bet this is the same technique to prove the result that you mention in your answer.

Comment: Might work, I'd have to think about it. The proof in my answer is from a completely different standpoint and aims to prove *weak* lower semicontinuity.

Comment: But it still might be wrong. If $(\phi_{n_k})$ is the subsequence you mentioned, then $\displaystyle \liminf_k \int_\Omega \lvert \phi_{n_k} \rvert~\mathrm{d}x$ might not be $\displaystyle \liminf_n \int_\Omega \lvert \phi_{n} \rvert~\mathrm{d}x$. Maybe you could carry out your proof in its entirety, I'd be thrilled to see it.

Comment: @Meowdog choose the subsequence such that $\liminf_n\int |\nabla\phi_n| = \lim_k \int |\nabla \phi_{n_k}|$. Then take a pointwise converging subsequence of this subsequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easy" reason for this inequality is that $\xi \mapsto \lvert \xi \rvert$ is a convex mapping on $\mathbb{R}^d$. The link between convexity and this lower semicontinuity result is not obvious.

It holds that if $f: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $(t, x, \xi) \mapsto f(t, x, \xi)$ is measurable in $t$, continuous in $(x, \xi)$ and convex in $\xi$, then the functional $I: W^{1, p}(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$
I(u) := \int_{\Omega} f(t, u(t), \nabla u(t))~\mathrm{d}t
$$
is weakly lower semicontinuous and thus lower semicontinuous for $p \in (1, \infty)$ and $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ open and bounded. If $\Omega$ has Lipschitz-boundary, we can even allow $p \in [1, \infty)$.

You can read about this (and a lot more) in chapter 1 and 3 of *Bernard Dacorogna -
Direct Methods in the Calculus of Variations*.

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate on daw's idea described in the comments. I hope it's OK to post someone else's ideas - I just thought this shouldn't get lost in case other people look in here.

---

The argument is basically Fatou's lemma, modulo some basic subsequence business. So let's start by choosing a subsequence $n_k$ such that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla\phi_{n_k}(x)| dx
= \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla\phi_n(x)| dx.
$$
Since $\nabla \phi_{n_k}$ is convergent to $\nabla \phi$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, we may choose a further subsequence $n_{k_l}$ such that $\nabla \phi_{n_{k_l}} \to \nabla \phi$ a.e., in consequence also $|\nabla \phi_{n_{k_l}}| \to |\nabla \phi|$ a.e. Then by Fatou's lemma
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla \phi(x)| dx 
= \int_\Omega \liminf_{l \to \infty} |\nabla \phi_{n_{k_l}}|
\le \liminf_{l \to \infty} \int_\Omega |\nabla \phi_{n_{k_l}}|.
$$
By our choice of subsequences, the latter $\liminf$ is actually a $\lim$, and it's equal to $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla\phi_n(x)| dx$.

Comment: Oh nice, I think I have no objections...